# How to make a conduit an instance of "Foldable"

Tags: haskell, typeclass

How do I make a Producer an instance of foldable, so:

```
foldr f2 init2 $ Data.Conduit.List.unfold f init
```

happily returns a value.

I've done this with Streams quite easily as below:

```
instance Foldable (Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Stream) where
  foldr = Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.foldr
```

But I can't get it to work with conduits.

Comment: If some type is not an instance of a standard class, it's generally probably a good idea to _not_ add it as an orphan instance but rather look for a higher-level abstraction that has the desired instance. – Anyway... what's the particular instance you've tried with Conduit, and what error do you get when trying this?

Comment: afaik [Data.Conduit.List](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/conduit/Data-Conduit-List.html) should give you anything you need

Comment: I'm trying to make it "Foldable". As in Data.Foldable

Comment: Yeah. Codez&Errorz, PLZ!

Comment: Most likely a `Foldable` instance- at least done the naive way- won't be what you're looking for. You most likely want to fold over the output stream from a conduit, but `Foldable` requires that the values be the final type argument, which will just be the return value (usually `()`). You'll likely need a newtype wrapper to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael mentioned above, it's impossible to implement `Foldable` directly on a conduit. This is because given the type:

```
data ConduitM i o m r = ...
```

the parameter we want to fold over (`o`) is not in the final position.

That said, we can work around this using a `newtype`, which lets us shuffle the parameters around. Something like this:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

newtype FoldableSource a = FoldableSource (ConduitM () a Identity ())

instance F.Foldable FoldableSource where
    foldMap f (FoldableSource s) = runIdentity $ s $$ CL.foldMap f
    foldl' f z (FoldableSource s) = runIdentity $ s $$ CL.fold f z
    -- GHC 7.10 only
    -- toList (FoldableSource s) = runIdentity $ s $$ CL.consume s

-- A silly example
main = print $ F.sum $ FoldableSource $ CL.sourceList [1..10]
```